# How to get a refresh token or redirect_uri for Salesforce API with python?

Tags: api, chatter, redirect, python, refresh-token

I'd like to use [this PYTHON API Client Library](https://github.com/nixmc/chatter/) to access the Chatter API

```
client_id = "YOUR_CHATTER_CLIENT_ID"
client_secret = "YOUR_CHATTER_CLIENT_SECRET"
auth = chatter.ChatterAuth(client_id, client_secret)

instance_url = "YOUR_USER_INSTANCE_URL"
access_token = "YOUR_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN"
refresh_token = "YOUR_USER_REFRESH_TOKEN"

chatter = chatter.Chatter(auth=auth, instance_url=instance_url, 
                          access_token=access_token, refresh_token=refresh_token)
```

I have all the information except the refresh_token, which I'm not sure where to get or how to retrieve. I get the following error as a result

```
(401, [{u'errorCode': u'INVALID_SESSION_ID', u'message': u'Session expired or invalid'}])
```

I've tried using [this library](https://github.com/heroku/salesforce-oauth-request) to get a refresh token, but I don't have a redirect_uri or know what that is. See below for the error I receive

CODE

```
result = salesforce_oauth_request.login(username='MySFDCEmail',
                                        password="MySFDCPassword",
                                        client_id="MySFDCClientId",
                                        client_secret="MySFDCClientSecret",
                                        redirect_uri="NO IDEA WHERE TO GET")
```

RESULT

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2217, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1643, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Shippy/API/chatter_api.py", line 28, in <module>
    redirect_uri="NONE")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salesforce_oauth_request-1.0.6-py2.7.egg/salesforce_oauth_request/utils.py", line 47, in login
    state = state)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salesforce_oauth_request-1.0.6-py2.7.egg/salesforce_oauth_request/utils.py", line 97, in website_login
    redirect_return = oauth_flow(s, auth_url, username=username, password=password, sandbox=sandbox)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salesforce_oauth_request-1.0.6-py2.7.egg/salesforce_oauth_request/utils.py", line 116, in oauth_flow
    raise RuntimeError(r.text)
RuntimeError: error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration
```

Answer (score 1):

The `redirect_uri` is the Callback URL that you define in your Connected App. See the documentation for [Setting up OAuth 2.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm) for more information.